# VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame returns OSStatus error code of -12780

Tags: ios8, video-encoding

I have a question regarding using VTCompressionSession in VideoToolbox on ios8.

My VTCompressionSession has setup properly without returning an error code. However, when I am trying to encode my frame using VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame, I got an OSStatus error code of -12780. I cannot find any defintion or explanation of such error code. Does anyone have any ideas ?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
CVPixelBufferRef input_frame_buffer_;
void* plane_ptrs[3] = {frame->channel[0], frame->channel[1], frame->channel[3]};
size_t plane_widths[3] = {frame->header.width,
   frame->header.width / 2, frame->header.width / 2};
size_t plane_heights[3] = {frame->header.height,
    frame->header.height / 2, frame->header.height / 2};

size_t plane_bytes_per_row[3] = {frame->stride[0], frame->stride[1], frame->stride[2]};


CVReturn pixel_buffer_status =

      CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault,

      frame->header.width,

      frame->header.height,

      (OSType) kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar,

      frame->channel[0],

      0,

      3,

      plane_ptrs,

      plane_widths,

      plane_heights,

      plane_bytes_per_row,

      &MyPixelBufferReleaseCallback,

      (void*)this,

      nullptr,

      &input_frame_buffer_);

 if (pixel_buffer_status != kCVReturnSuccess) {

      logger_->Error("CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes failed.");

      return;

   }

  VTEncodeInfoFlags info_flags;


  OSStatus status = VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(session_,

      input_frame_buffer_, frame->header.pts, kCMTimeInvalid, nullptr,

      mySourceFrameRefCon,

      &info_flags);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem before, you can follow these steps as below

1. List item

// 1. Get SPS,PPS form stream data, and create CMFormatDescription, VTDecompressionSession

// 2. create  CMFormatDescription

// 3. create VTDecompressionSession

// 4. get NALUnit payload into a CMBlockBuffer

// 5.  making sure to replace the separator code with a 4 byte length code (the length of the NalUnit including the unit code)

// 6. create a CMSampleBuffer

// 7. use VTDecompressionSessionDecodeFrame

// 8. use VideoToolBox Decompress Frame CallBack to get CVImageBufferRef

you can get the reference in my git https://github.com/htaiwan/HWDecoder

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass a value for the `dataSize` parameter. See my answer on the apple developers forum and this example code: https://gist.github.com/roxlu/79e50d2ac869763d712d

roxlu

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the pixel buffer pool from VTCompressionSesion.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1063536#1063536